# Pifox on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: gpio

The rasberry pi 2 is well known to be able to transmit low power radio emissions off of the GPIO pins. I am a licensed amateur radio operator, and am trying to use the program [pifox](https://github.com/km4efp/pifox), a foxhunt transmitter on the rasberry pi 2. (A game involving radio direction finding)

Before experimenting with pifox, I tried [pifm](http://www.icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Turning_the_Raspberry_Pi_Into_an_FM_Transmitter), a wide-band fm transmitter for the rasberry pi. Unfortunately, this did not work, but I did find another script fm_transmitter which worked on the raspberry pi 2.

There is obviously some difference with the GPIO that is not allowing pifox or pifm to work. Does anybody know how I can solve this and get pifox to work on the rasberry pi 2?

Comment: Maybe add a bit more detail. How is pifox not working? Does it start and say it's working? Does it show an error message?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you following a tutorial? if do which one? What code are you using? How do you know it is not working? Please edit your question and add these details. based on your question you have not yet tried Pifox, but your subject mentions pifox.

Answer (score 0):

PiFm works only with the old version of the raspberry pi.
There is a long discussion here about the topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/2wcgpp/

This is a package that enables the Raspberry pi 2 to transmit in FM:
https://github.com/markondej/fm_transmitter

Cheers,

Fabio

Comment: Thanks for the information, this info is wideband only though, I am looking for narrow band for the ham radio band